# Row-wise comparison of two Pandas DataFrames to extract matched results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rowwise

I have a pandas DataFrame called `df_ref` which is like:

```
    a                   b               c               result
0   (-0.001, 0.00482]   (-0.001, 1.0]   (-0.001, 1.0]   0.622745
1   (-0.001, 0.00482]   (-0.001, 1.0]   (-0.001, 1.0]   0.450869
2   (-0.001, 0.00482]   (-0.001, 1.0]   (1.0, 5.0]      0.693840
3   (-0.001, 0.00482]   (-0.001, 1.0]   (1.0, 5.0]      0.484881
4   (-0.001, 0.00482]   (-0.001, 1.0]   (5.0, 13.0]     0.687814
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
91  (17.953, 90.0]  (4.0, 480.0]    (1.0, 5.0]          0.500905
92  (17.953, 90.0]  (4.0, 480.0]    (5.0, 13.0]         0.500905
93  (17.953, 90.0]  (4.0, 480.0]    (5.0, 13.0]         0.500905
94  (17.953, 90.0]  (4.0, 480.0]    (13.0, 1103.0]      0.500905
95  (17.953, 90.0]  (4.0, 480.0]    (13.0, 1103.0]      0.500905
```

and another DataFrame called `df` which is like:

```
        a           b       c       
1       0.004213    11.0    11.0
2       32.326794   0.0     0.0 
3       5.415845    1.0     1.0 
4       0.001968    10.0    41.0    
5       0.014745    9.0     13.0    
... ... ... ... ... ...
1435435 0.000185    1.0     1.0 
1435436 89.999919   0.0     0.0 
1435437 4.788090    1.0     1.0 
1435438 7.441620    0.0     22.0    
1435439 0.001053    1.0     1.0
```

I want each row of `df` be compared to all the rows of `df_ref` and determine which row they belong to, and extract the corresponding `result` value from `df_ref` and put those values in a list with 1,435,439 elements (or just a new column in `df`, both works). Since the data is large this need to be efficiently coded, so I understand that probably a simple loop is not the best approach, and that's why I am asking for help.

Comment: If you have got the dfs by printing from the df =pd.DataFrame() method or Jason, can you share that please

Comment: @wwnde Sorry I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you explain please?

Comment: Its harder to use your datframes because they are chunky. if you have got for instance an object you used to print them it makes things easier. For instance df=pd.DataFrame ({'a':[0,1]}) much easier and faster to use than a plotted column a with 2 values

Comment: @wwnde Sorry, no I don't. The objects are given to me as pandas dataframes.

Comment: How do you determine which row in df_ref a specific row in df "belongs to"?  are you matching df(a, b, c) to df_ref(a[0], b[0], c[0]) or something?

Comment: @BobMcCormick In df_ref the values for a, b, and c are numerical intervals. The rows of df match to the rows of df_ref, if the values of a, b, and c from df fall into the right intervals. Sorry I had to explain better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the type of the values in columns `a`, `b` and `c` of `df_ref` are [intervalIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html) and that combining them you always get a unique combination. If it is the case then I guess the solution could be simply a matter of setting the indexes for the two dfs and combining them as pe

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd 
   ...:  
   ...: df_ref = pd.DataFrame({ 
   ...:     "a": pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(-0.001, 0.00482), (-0.001, 0.00482), (-0.001, 0.00482), (-0.001, 0.00482), (1, 2)]), 
   ...:     "b": pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(-0.001, 1.0), (-0.001, 1.0), (-0.001, 1.0), (1., 2.), (2, 3)]), 
   ...:     "c": pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(-0.001, 1.0), (1.0, 2.0), (2.0, 5.0), (5.1, 10.0), (1, 2)]), 
   ...:     'result': [0.622745, 0.450869, 0.693840, 0.484881, 10] 
   ...: }) 
   ...:  
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 0.003, 'b': 0.004, 'c': 0.4}, {'a': 2., 'b': 3, 'c': 0.1}])                                                                            

In [2]: df_ref_idx = df_ref.set_index(['a', 'b', 'c'])                                                                                                                  

In [3]: df_idx = df.set_index(['a', 'b', 'c'])                                                                                                                          

In [4]: df_idx['result'] = df_ref_idx['result']                                                                                                                         

In [5]: df_idx                                                                                                                                                          
Out[5]: 
                   result
a     b     c            
0.003 0.004 0.4  0.622745
2.000 3.000 0.1       NaN
```

It took me a bit to create dummy dataframes in the future you may want to share a snippet to easily recreate them (as per my answer) so that it is easier for others to help you.

Let me know if this doesn't help

Comment: Worked perfectly. Sorry for it took your time. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the following. Make a copy of `df_ref` called `df_ref2`, splitting the tuples into separate columns `a_low`, `a_high`, etc.  Then join the frames like this

```
df = df.join(df_ref2,
   on=( (df.a >= df_ref2.a_low) & (df.a <= df_ref2.a_high) &
        (df.b >= df_ref2.b_low) & (df.b <= df_ref2.b_high) &
        (df.c >= df_ref2.c_low) & (df.c <= df_ref2.c_high) ),
   how='inner')
df = df.drop('a_low', 'a_high', 'b_low', 'b_high', 'c_low', 'c_high')
```

Now you have the `result` column joined to `df`.  Note that you may have an increase in rows, since there each df row can match multiple df_ref rows, as you see the first two rows of df_ref have the same intervals.